# How to find if a value in a dictionary is in a certain range

Tags: dictionary

I need to determine if a year (which is a value in  a dictionary) is within a certain range of years. the dictionary looks like this: print(movies[3520029]) = {'genre': ['Sci-Fi', 'Action', 'Adventure'], 'movie_year': 2010, 'name': 'TRON: Legacy', 'rating': 6.8, 'numvotes': 254865}. there are numerous entries. I need to find the movies in a range between two years, which are inputs given by the user. Im not sure how to do this. i tried

```
for i in movies:
    vals = list(movies.values())
        if vals[2][0] >= minimum and vals[2][0] <= maximum:
            print(movie)
```

but i got builtins.KeyError: 0 and im not sure what that means, and im also not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think is Python 3.  Where you need to use list(dict.values()).

(1)The error is because there is no Index 0 inside vals[2], What is in vals[2]?

(2)You are not using i from the loop.

(3) Is movies a dict?

It should be something like this:

```
for key in movies:
     movie = movies[key]
     year= movie['movie_year']
```